# Почему не получается сохранить изображение на SD карту?

Tags: android, изображения, sd

Не получается сохранить изображение на SD карту. Скажите пожалуйста, в чем проблема?

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    ImageView imageView;
    Button take_photo;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);
        take_photo = (Button) findViewById(R.id.take_photo);


        take_photo.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                String folderToSave = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString();
                SavePicture(imageView,folderToSave);
            }
        });
    }
    private String SavePicture(ImageView imageView, String folderToSave)
    {
        OutputStream fOut = null;
        Time time = new Time();
        time.setToNow();

        try {
            File file = new File(folderToSave, Integer.toString(time.year) + Integer.toString(time.month) + Integer.toString(time.monthDay) + Integer.toString(time.hour) + Integer.toString(time.minute) + Integer.toString(time.second) +".jpg"); // создать уникальное имя для файла основываясь на дате сохранения
            fOut = new FileOutputStream(file);

            Bitmap bitmap = ((BitmapDrawable)imageView.getDrawable()).getBitmap();
            bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 85, fOut); // сохранять картинку в jpeg-формате с 85% сжатия.
            fOut.flush();
            fOut.close();
            MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage(getContentResolver(), file.getAbsolutePath(), file.getName(),  file.getName()); // регистрация в фотоальбоме
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Save!",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        catch (Exception e) // здесь необходим блок отслеживания реальных ошибок и исключений, общий Exception приведен в качестве примера
        {
            return e.getMessage();
        }
        return "";
    }
}
```

````
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/activity_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="300dp"
        android:layout_height="180dp"
        android:src="@drawable/dummyphoto"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/take_photo"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Take Photo"
        android:background="@color/colorAccent"
        android:textColor="#fff"
        android:textSize="22sp"
        android:textAllCaps="false"
        android:layout_margin="15dp"
        android:padding="8dp"/>

</LinearLayout>```
       `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>` - тоже поключил
````

Comment: А что не получается то?

Comment: Думается мне, что разрешение на запись требовательно запрашивать и в коде. Запись во внешнее хранилище - опасное разрешение, подробнее см. [здесь](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/permissions/overview#permission-groups).

Comment: Смотрите. Я установил на телефон это приложение, нажал на кнопку сохранить. Зашел на sd карту, а там нету этого изображения. Либо я чего не понимаю либо оно не работает и в действительности... Может кто этот код у себя проверить? Пожалуйста очень нужно. Уже 3 дня на это потратил

Comment: Попробуйте сохранить любой пустой файл на sd карту. Если сохранится то тогда вы неправильно сохраняете картинку

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте этот код для сохранения изображения(iv=imageview):

```
BitmapDrawable draw = 
(BitmapDrawable) iv.getDrawable();
Bitmap bitmap = draw.getBitmap();

FileOutputStream outStream = null;
File sdCard = 
 Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
File dir = new 
File(sdCard.getAbsolutePath() + "/YourFolderName");
dir.mkdirs();
String fileName = String.format("%d.jpg", System.currentTimeMillis());
File outFile = new File(dir, fileName);
outStream = new FileOutputStream(outFile); 
bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, outStream);
outStream.flush();
outStream.close();
```

И добавьте это в манифест:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Comment: "%d" - Для чего? там же название картинки должно быть, нет?.

Comment: %d используется для форматирования текста.  https://javarush.ru/groups/posts/1412-formatiruem-vihvod-chisel-v-java

Answer (score 0):

На кнопку повешаем сохранение:

```
 public void saveImage (View v) {  //saveImage укажите в атрибуте onClick кнопки
    showDialogForSave(); 
    }

    //проверяем есть ли разрешение на сохранение изображения, если нет, то спрашиваем у        //пользователя
    private void showDialogForSave() {
    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)
    != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
    requestPermissions(new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, PERMISSION_REQUEST);
    }else {
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    builder.setTitle(getResources().getString(R.string.ColorfulDialog));        builder.setNegativeButton(getResources().getString(R.string.ColorfulDialogNegative), new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
    dialog.dismiss();
    }
    });
                builder.setPositiveButton(getResources().getString(R.string.ColorfulDialogPositive), new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
     @Override
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
    try {
    save();
    } catch (IOException e) {
     e.printStackTrace();
    }
    dialog.dismiss();
    }
    });
    builder.show();
    }
    }

    //результат запроса разрешений
    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
    if (requestCode == PERMISSION_REQUEST && grantResults.length > 0&& grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
    try {
    save();
    } catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    }
    }
    }

    //сохранеям изображение
    private void save() throws IOException{
    Bitmap bitmap = paintView.getBitmap();
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss", Locale.getDefault());
    String datetime = sdf.format(new Date());
    String file_name =  "MyPicture_" +datetime+ ".png";
    OutputStream outputStream;
    boolean saved;
    File folder;
    //проверяем если у пользователя версия андроид 10+
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.Q) {
    folder = new File(getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES)
    + File.separator + "Coloring for kids");
    } else {
    folder = newFile(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES)
    + File.separator + "Coloring for kids");
    }
    if (!folder.exists())
    folder.mkdirs();
    File subFolder = new File(folder, Common.ITEM_SELECTED);
    if (!subFolder.exists())
    subFolder.mkdirs();
    File image = new File(subFolder+File.separator+file_name);
    Uri imageUri = Uri.fromFile(image);
    outputStream = new FileOutputStream(image);
    saved = bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG,100, outputStream);
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.Q) {
     ContentResolver resolver  = getContentResolver();
     ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
     contentValues.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.DISPLAY_NAME,file_name);
     contentValues.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.MIME_TYPE, "image/png");
     contentValues.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.RELATIVE_PATH, 
    Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES+File.separator+getString(R.string.app_name));
    Uri uri = resolver.insert(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,contentValues);
              outputStream = resolver.openOutputStream(uri);
              saved = bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, outputStream);
    }else{
    sendPictureToGallery(imageUri);
    }
    if(saved)        Toast.makeText(Colorful.this,getResources().getText(R.string.savePictureToGallery), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    else
    Toast.makeText(Colorful.this,getResources().getString(R.string.failedToSave), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    outputStream.flush();
    outputStream.close();
    finish();
    }
    private void sendPictureToGallery(Uri imageUri) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE);
    intent.setData(imageUri);
    sendBroadcast(intent);
    }
```

И в манифесте не забудьте указать разрешения на запись